# preg_match() function gives different results on different servers

Tags: php, validation, preg-match

I tried reading the other questions first but didn't find anything useful.
I am using **preg_match()** function for UAE phone number validation,everything is working fine on localhost(XAMPP).But when it comes to production server am not getting the result i expect.

Php version: **7.2**, Server OS: **CentOS 7.4** (inmotion hosting)

Sample code for validation is given below,

```
$phone="971588471481";
$pattern = "/^(?:\971|00971)?(?:50|51|52|54|55|56|58|2|3|4|6|7|9)\d{7}$/";

if(preg_match($pattern, $phone)) {
   echo "Match Result: <b>valid Phone Number</b>";
}else{
   echo "Match Result: <b>Phone number is not valid</b>";
}
```

when i run the above code on my localhost the result is **valid phone number**. But on live server the same script gives opposite result.(**Invalid Phone number**). why it is giving different results?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you escape `9`? Do not escape it, word characters can't/shouldn't be escaped.

Comment: I got that pattern from here. https://regex101.com/r/uX8nW2/1 .Could you give the match pattern for the above phone number. i tried that pattern on localhost and it is working there. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: [Here](https://3v4l.org/rRs5P) it works (I just optimized the pattern a bit), too. Sorry, I have no access to your site, you should do that on your own.

Comment: Thank you so much. You save my day. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: What has finally worked for you? `$pattern = "/^(?:(?:00)?971)?(?:5[0124568]|[234679])\d{7}$/";`?

Comment: i used your pattern that you provided and it work like charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP7, regexp efficiency is analyzed before execution, and if it is too complex from the engine point of view, execution may be halted.

You should write your patterns in a more optimized way to avoid so many alternatives that can match at the same location in the group.

You may optimize your regex the following way:

```
$pattern = "/^(?:(?:00)?971)?(?:5[0124568]|[234679])\d{7}$/";
```

See the [PHP online demo](https://3v4l.org/rRs5P).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:(?:00)?971)?` - an optional sequence of

  - `(?:00)?` - optional sequence of `00`
  - `971` - a `971` substring
- `(?:` - either

  - `5[0124568]` -`5` followed with `0`, `1`, `2`, `4`, `5`, `6` or `8`
  - `|` - or
  - `[234679]` - `2`, `3`, `4`, `6`, `7` or `9`
- `)` - end of the grouping
- `\d{7}` - 7 digits
- `$` - end of string  (or `\z` can be used here)/